# Textarea slowly autoscroll down

Tags: java, swing

I need to display some text on a text area from a txt file. Ive read all the lines into an arraylist and i append these onto the textarea.

Now i need to slowly scroll downward, in a speed people would be able to read if it was display on, say, a monitor somewhere.

I've tried using the defaultcaret method ive found in all the other questions this was asked, but i cant get it to work. I've also tried using a scrollpane but with no luck.

```
 private void displayWords() {
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setPreferredSize(this.getPreferredSize());
    textArea.setFont(font);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setAutoscrolls(true);
    DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) textArea.getCaret();
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
    textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(50, 50, 50, 50));
    for (String s : lines) {
        textArea.append(s + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }

    /*
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(textare);
    scrollpane.setPreferredSize(this.getPreferredSize());
    scrollpane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollpane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollpane.setAutoscrolls(true);
    scrollpane.setViewportView(textare);
    */

    add(textArea);
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: Use a Swing `Timer`.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: `JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setPreferredSize(this.getPreferredSize());`  That would better be something like `JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5,20); // suggest a size`

Comment: Might be a little complicated, but you'd get the idea - [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604399/simple-way-of-creating-an-animated-jscrollpane-in-java/15605803#15605803)

Comment: the setSize thing, is because its a fullscreen panel with a gridbaglayout. its just to fill it out. But ill try using a timer to set the caret

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's written in the commented section place the JTExtArea in a JScrollPane. Start a Timer and on each actionPerformed() scroll it down by setValue() of the vertical scrollbar

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class TAScroll {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f=new JFrame();
        JTextArea ta=new JTextArea();
        for (int i=0;i<50; i++) {
            ta.append(i+"\n");
        }
        final JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(ta);
        f.add(scroll);

        Timer t=new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue()+10);
                if (scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue()>=scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum()) {
                    ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                }
            }
        });

        t.start();

        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setSize(200,100);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could set the caret position or set the viewports viewable area, might be more reliable then changing the scrollbar value...just saying...

Comment: You are rigth. It's just fast solution. It also does not stop the timer actually:)

Comment: The idea's fine, I just fine `JScrollBar#setValue` to be unreliable ;)