# Smoothing Swing animations

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, tween

I would like to know how to smooth the automatic transition of a JScrollPane. I'm using

```
JScrollBar scroll = scollpane.getVerticalScrollBar();
scroll.setValue(scroll.getMaximum());
```

Something like `JScrollPane.setUnitIncrement(inc)` with inc values of **~0.001** and a **10ms** delay between increments would help, I guess, but `setUnitIncrement` only takes `int`s.

Also, I want the same smooth animation for adding an element like `JList` to a `JPanel` with `BoxLayout`. I'd like it to have a smooth top-to-bottom appearance, not instantly being displayed when using `JPanel.add(JList)`.

I'm mostly looking towards an implementation of **AurelienRibon's** `SlidingLayout` or `Tween`, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604399/simple-way-of-creating-an-animated-jscrollpane-in-java/15605803#15605803)?

Comment: Adding a time delay alone doesn't help. I can't get the scrollbar to transition between lines. It only advances one line at a time. As for my other request, the main problem is gradually displaying the JList.
Also, I'm preety new to java so there may be an easy way out.

Comment: I think you need to explain better what it is you want to achieve. The linked example will cause the scroll pane to scroll automatically over time

Comment: You can think of it like scrolling through the notepad window. It will never land the view on a half line. So does my application, it scrolls one line at a time and I want it to scroll 0.1 or less of a line at a time.

Comment: *"an easy way out*" - While Swing can do animation, it wasn't designed for it from the get go. There are some tricks you can do, for example, using a proxy layout manager to inject animation, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368190/too-many-jpanels-inside-a-jpanel-with-gridbaglayout/32372506#32372506), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540080/animations-when-using-gridbag-layout/14541651#14541651) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463989/java-moving-jlabel-twice-using-timer/27466801#27466801)

Comment: Or even do something more complex like [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645202/set-jbutton-to-the-location-of-another-jbutton/29651705#29651705)

Comment: `I want it to scroll 0.1 or less of a line at a time.` - you can scroll 1 pixel at a time. If it doesn't work, then your code is wrong. Since you didn't post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem we can't help. So create a simple GUI with a scroll pane and a "Start Scrolling" button. The button will start a Timer and change the value of the scrollbar by 1 pixel every time the Timer fires.

Comment: Seems you're right. I have a dubious Thread.wait() in my project that is messing with Thread.sleep and forces a bad scrollbar update. I did a workaround with DeltaTime and it updates well now.
Also, the animated [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368190/too-many-jpanels-inside-a-jpanel-with-gridbaglayout/32372506#32372506) was just what I was looking for. Thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smooth animations (any type, in any program) are done with implementations of [`Delta-Time`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_timing).

Most frameworks use a `Delta-Time` pattern (the ones that don't are doing it wrong, because other methods are prone to `Time-Drifting` bugs), and are hard to understand if you don't grasp the concept of `Delta-Time` first.